# Running an .ipynb file from Lambda function

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sagemaker

I'm New on AWS. I want to run a .ipynb file on Sagemaker notebook instance. I'm using runipy package on lambda to run a .ipynb file "/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/xxxxxxxxxx.ipynb" from Lambda function with s3 trigger but failed. 
Can someone suggest how to run .ipynb file from labdda in anyways possible.

**Error**

```
[ERROR] FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/xxxxxxxx.ipynb' Traceback (most recent call last): File "/var/task/classifier.py", line 10, in lambda_handler notebook = read(open("/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/xxxxx.ipynb"), 'json')

/var/task/IPython/nbformat.py:13: ShimWarning: The IPython.nbformat package has been deprecated since IPython 4.0. You should import from nbformat instead
```

Comment: Failed with what error?

Comment: [ERROR] FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/xxxxxxxx.ipynb'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/classifier.py", line 10, in lambda_handler
    notebook = read(open("/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/xxxxx.ipynb"), 'json')

Comment: /var/task/IPython/nbformat.py:13: ShimWarning: The `IPython.nbformat` package has been deprecated since IPython 4.0. You should import from nbformat instead.

Comment: I don't understand how did you try to load a file from ec2 to lambda. It is totally different server and you cannot refer the file from ec2.

Comment: exactly, I understand the problem but is there any way to load a file from sagemaker to lambda?

Comment: Jupyter on EMR, there is an option to save the notebook into S3. So if there exists such an option in SageMaker, you can download the notebook from S3 to lambda and can do something. I am not sure about the S3 saving option for SageMager.

Answer (score 0):

This is a general case of bundling your dependencies onto Lambda. You can follow the instructions at [the Lambda documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html) for bundling files and packages along with your function code.

Inside your Lambda function code, you can use [nbconvert](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to execute the notebook file during a Lambda execution.